# How to change text size of dialog preference message?

Tags: android, preferences

I have a class that extends `EditTextPreference` and I use it in my own layout, such as:

```
    <com.app.MyEditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/key"
        android:title="@string/title"
        android:summary="@string/summary"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/title"
        android:dialogMessage="@string/message"
        android:layout="@layout/preference_edittext"/>
```

My app theme inherits from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and I have changed the values of the text sizes:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item> <!-- was 14sp -->
</style>
```

However, when the preference dialog is displayed, the size of the message is different than the one I have defined in my style.

So how do I set the text size of the dialog message correctly?

**EDIT**

I copied the dialog layout from the sdk:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+android:id/edittext_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/message"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Small" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However, I get a build error `Resource is not public` on the line `android:id="@+android:id/edittext_container"`.

And if I change it to `"@*android:id/edittext_container"`, the edit text is not visible anymore.

Is there a simpler way to just change the textsize of the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to change the message text size by:

a) Changing the id of the `LinearLayout` to: `@+id/edittext_container`, and

b) Adding the following code in my class extending `EditTextPreference`:

```
@Override
protected void onAddEditTextToDialogView(View dialogView, EditText editText) {
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) dialogView
            .findViewById(R.id.edittext_container);

    if (container != null) {
        container.addView(editText, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

This works fine and is clearly a valid answer, however a simpler solution would be to just change the message text size through themeing.

Answer (score 0):

First create new xml file name cus.xml in layout folder.
it need for set the view for dialog at runtime .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter Name :"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="18dp" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
```

As you need dialog: 
here's dialog code:

```
Dialog d=new Dialog(getActivity());
                d.setTitle("Image Title");
                d.setContentView(R.layout.cus);
                d.show();
```